Use MERGE with CTE
Does Postgresql allow use of cte as source of the MERGE instruction ?
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS graph
(
    idgraph SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    from_table varchar(128)
);

WITH cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT 'tag' AS from_table
)
MERGE INTO graph g
USING cte2 ON g.from_table = cte2.from_table 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN
        INSERT(from_table) 
        VALUES(cte2.from_table)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN
        DELETE;

What the Postgresql doc says about CTEs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING
You can use data-modifying statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE) in WITH.
What https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html says:
syntax error at or near "MERGE"
And pglite does produce an error message:
syntax error at or near "BY"
Who should I trust ? I am using pglite wasm in browser.
Here is the version info:
PostgreSQL 16.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 3.1.68 (ceee49d2ecdab36a3feb85a684f8e5a453dde910), 32-bit"

The official docs are almost invariably correct. Why do you think they are wrong? (random websites don't count - if you can produce an error in an installed instance you can provide details about then this is worth investigating though)

pglite does produce an error message: syntax error at or near "BY"

when I google on "Postgresql merge cte" I find very little information, looks like this feature is not the most frequently used

Perhaps you don't have the right PostgreSQL version? You didn't tell us what you are running.

PostgreSQL 16.4 ... is what I get when I call SELECT version()

according to the docs, BY TARGET and BY SOURCE were only introduced in PostregSQL 17, this is why pglite(PostgreSQL 16.4) is saying "syntax error at or near BY"

@Laurenz Albe, if you post this as answer, I will accept it. Thanks to you !

Switching the docs version shows this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-merge.html so more of a typo than anything else.

The link for the Postgres documents you show is for current which at this time is version 17. You are working with version 16 and that is the difference, read why here 17 Release Notes: E.3.3.4. MERGE.

This could be causing issues with version 17 too:
From the docs:

The WHEN clause may specify WHEN MATCHED, WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE, or WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]. Note that the SQL standard only defines WHEN MATCHED and WHEN NOT MATCHED (which is defined to mean no matching target row). WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE is an extension to the SQL standard, as is the option to append BY TARGET to WHEN NOT MATCHED, to make its meaning more explicit.

... and a warning from the docs:

Only columns from the target table that attempt to match data_source rows should appear in join_condition. join_condition subexpressions that only reference the target table's columns can affect which action is taken, often in surprising ways.


If both WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET] clauses are specified, the MERGE command will perform a FULL join between data_source and the target table. For this to work, at least one join_condition subexpression must use an operator that can support a hash join, or all of the subexpressions must use operators that can support a merge join.

More about it
WITH cte2 AS 
  ( SELECT 'tag' AS from_table )
MERGE INTO graph g
USING cte2 ON(g.from_table = cte2.from_table)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(from_table) VALUES(cte2.from_table)

Select * From graph

Result:



idgraph
from_table




1
tag



fiddle
